# API to find local business/place using phone number

Tags: api, geolocation, phone-number, simplegeo, geoapi

Looking for an API that will give me a venue/place/local business based on a phone number as input. I checked out the google place/foursquare/simple geo API's but they don't seem to have this functionality. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Yelp at http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/phone_api